# jQuery ajax call not hitting controller due large string data parameter

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

In my view file, I'm making an ajax call as follows:

```
 $.ajax(
    {

        url: '@Url.Action("LMTDetailDashboardList", "DetailUsage")',
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            ServerID: ServerID,
            LicenseId: LicenseId,
            company: company,
            fromDate: fromDate,
            toDate: toDate,
            fromhour: fromHour,
            toHour: toHour
        },
        type: "GET",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#divLoading").show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            LMTDetailDashboardChart(data, Zaxis);
            return false;
        },
        @*error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },*@
            //error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
            //    alert('Exception:', exception);
            //},
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("error");
           console.log('Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            },
        complete: function () {
            $("#divLoading").hide();
            $("#exportuserlist").show();
        }
        });
    return false;
```

The controller code is as follows:

```
 public JsonResult LMTDetailDashboardList(String ServerID, String LicenseId, String Company, String FromDate, String ToDate, String FromHour, String ToHour)
    {

        int nameLength = Company.Length;
        int nameLength2 = ServerID.Length;
        int nameLength3 = LicenseId.Length;
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(Company);



        LMTUsage objLMT = new LMTUsage();
        LMTDAL objLMTDAL = new LMTDAL();

        TempData["Company"] = Company;
        TempData["ServerID"] = ServerID;
        TempData["LicenseId"] = LicenseId;
        TempData["FromDate"] = FromDate;
        TempData["ToDate"] = ToDate;
        TempData["FromHour"] = FromHour;
        TempData["ToHour"] = ToHour;

        if (object.Equals(ServerID, null))
        {
            ServerID = "All";
        }
        try
        {
            var response = objLMTDAL.GetLMTDetailUsage(ServerID, LicenseId, Company, FromDate, ToDate, FromHour, ToHour);
            if (!object.Equals(response, null))
            {
                objLMT.LMTDetailUsageList = response.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return Json(objLMT.LMTDetailUsageList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When the "company" value is smaller in length/size ajax call hits the controller action but when it is larger, it throws an error and it doesn't hit the controller method.
I have tried to rectify errors in many ways but not able to get it. With browser debugger, I am now getting following error.   [Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfD7B.png)
Note: "company" variable contains the comma separated values from the multi-select drop-down.
Kindly put some light on it.

Comment: Make it a POST instead of GET

Comment: The method is used to getting the data from DB and not to POST it.

Comment: You can still use a POST! (its a GET which you do not use for altering data)

Comment: And its common to do so when making an ajax call - you do not want users navigating to that method

Comment: GET has a small limit to it..  IE limits it to 2048 characters (inc URL etc) but I think most servers are 8k. to exceed that POST is the only way to go

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks a lot. It worked. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the information @BugFinder

Comment: @StephenMuecke Perhaps post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the data length. The GET requests have length restrictions. That's why the ajax call not hitting the controller. You can use a POST instead of GET method. The POST requests have no restrictions on data length.

Change the 'type' using the following way:

> type: "POST",

Your final script will be:

```
$.ajax(
    {

        url: '@Url.Action("LMTDetailDashboardList", "DetailUsage")',
        dataType: "json",
        data:
        {
            ServerID: ServerID,
            LicenseId: LicenseId,
            company: company,
            fromDate: fromDate,
            toDate: toDate,
            fromhour: fromHour,
            toHour: toHour
        },
        type: "POST",
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#divLoading").show();
        },
        success: function (data) {
            LMTDetailDashboardChart(data, Zaxis);
            return false;
        },
        @*error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            toastr.error(err.message);
        },*@
            //error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
            //    alert('Exception:', exception);
            //},
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           alert("error");
           console.log('Could not get posts, server response: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            },
        complete: function () {
            $("#divLoading").hide();
            $("#exportuserlist").show();
        }
        });
    return false;
```

Good Luck!